# Java counter loop

Tags: java

I am very new to programming and trying to grasp the idea on how to count down in Java.

I want to run a program that requires you to enter 5 songs in this form:

```
Please enter song 1: "Thriller"
Choose 4 more songs.
```

So I am counting back from 5 to 1, can I get some ideas on how to do this? Here is my poor attempt below, but notice my counter increments up (this is not what I want).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testing {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String song;
        int amount = 0;
        Scanner kdb = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (amount < 5) {
            System.out.println("enter song:");
            song = kdb.next();
            amount++;
            System.out.println("you chose " + song + amount + " more required");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then instead of incrementing, decrement and change the while loop condition.

Comment: amunt-- instead of amount++

Comment: Also, since the number of iteration is fixed and known before, you can also use a `for loop`.

Comment: Fix: `int amount = 5;` and `while (amount > 0) {` and `amount--;`. And actually you can use `for` loop instead of `while`: `for (int amount = 5; amount > 0; amount--) {`.

Comment: thanks guys, I couldnt get it right with the decrement earlier because I forgot to change the while condition. Appreciate it.. Im struggling with for loops have you an example of this in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `amount++` (same as `amount = amount + 1`).  It should be `amount--` (same as `amount = amount - 1`).

Rewritten program (with `for` loop):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String song;
        Scanner kdb = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int amount = 5; amount > 0; amount--) {
            System.out.println("Enter song:");
            song = kdb.next();
            System.out.println("You chose " + song + ". Choose" + amount + " more");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not runnin into `Infinite Loop`?

Comment: amount = 5; amount > 0; --amount

Comment: I was meaning to put that, was getting a little confused with the OP's requirements.

Comment: thanks for that for loop. all good now.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I would do it,

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String song;
        int amount = 1;
        Scanner kdb = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (amount <= 5) {
            System.out.println("enter song:");
            song = kdb.next();
            if(amount<5){
            System.out.println("you chose " + song + amount + " more required");
            }
            ++amount;
        }

    }
```